# Python - Что делать, если нужно подключится к базе данных, но код должен быть у пользователя? Как защитить параметры пользователя и пароля

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql, sql, база-данных

Пишу программу. Столкнулся с проблемой, что нужно подключиться к базе данных, но при этом код будет находиться у человека на компьютере.

Нужно как-то защитить данные `username` и `password` так, чтобы пользователь не мог их узнать.

Использую Python 3.11

Comment: Поздравляю, ваш код требует клиент серверной реализации :) т.е. одна программа у клиента, вторая на сервере :)

Comment: можете пожалуйста поделиться каким-нибудь уроком, где описаны хотя бы базовые принципы такой реализации кода.

Comment: Могу посоветовать, но не уверен что вам будет понятен материал... https://habr.com/ru/post/580710/ кмк подача материала на очень простом уровне...

Comment: Странная реализация - база на стороне клиента и он не должен узнать имя и пароль. А зачем ему эти данные? В большенстве баз можно и так посмотреть данные в базе под админом

Comment: @Виктор,а что не так с таким запросом?) кто сказал что пользователь должен знать пароль админа базы?))  https://v8.1c.ru/platforma/faylovyy-variant-raboty/

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Я же написа - "В большенстве баз"